# workflow rule that changes a picklist value

Tags: workflow, leads, time-dependent-workflow, criteria

I am trying to develop a workflow rule that will change a certain picklist value of the Pipeline field based on a certain criteria.

I've created the workflow rule *Test Workflow Rule* and

- set the **Evaluation Criteria** to *created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria* and
- inside in **Rule Criteria** I've setup formula evaluates to true [this is where i place my certain criteria and actually the part where i need help with]

Criteria:

> Pipeline__c = 'Short Listed' && Feedback__c = '' && Called__c = False
>   Call_Atmpt__c = False && Status__c = 'Sent' && Lead LastModifiedDate
>   to be older than 6 months.

Based on that criteria I want the workflow to update the Pipeline__c field into Not Responding.

Additional info based on the information provided in answers and where and what error I get.

[image]

Can you please advise me on the formula part?

Thanks in advance,
Darko

Comment: What is th eproblem, you are facing currently? I think you can check the condition in rule criteria itself (criteria are met) meaning without formula- except last modified date.

Comment: I am not sure how to pack the formula and also i am confused how to define the date to be older than 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
AND(
  Pipeline__c = 'Short Listed',
  Feedback__c = '',
  Called__c = False 
  Call_Atmpt__c = False,
  Status__c = 'Sent', 
  (TODAY() - DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate)) >=  180
)
```

if any of the fields are picklist fields then you have use ISPICKVAL function instead of direct string compare..

something like

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(Pipeline__c, 'Short Listed'),
  Feedback__c = '',
  Called__c = False 
  Call_Atmpt__c = False,
  ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Sent'), 
  (TODAY() - DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate)) >=  180
)
```

Comment: Vamsi, I think subtraction of dates doesn't work in formula, did you check this ?

Comment: if both are date fields it will directly work.. and if they are date time fields u jus need to wrap them inside the DATEVALUE function..

Comment: last time you missed the DATEVALUE function ;)

Comment: Hey guys,
See below what i did followed by the error.
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(Pipeline__c, 'Short Listed'),
  Feedback__c = '',
  Called__c = False 
  Call_Atmpt__c = False,
  ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Sent'), 
  (TODAY() - DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate)) >=  180.
)

Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, received DateTime

Comment: can u edit ur question and post a screenshot of what you are seeing.. also there is a decimal / dot after 180 in your formula which needs to be removed.

Comment: Hey Vamsi, I've posted a picture with the error i get.

Comment: u hv to use  DATEVALUE(Lead.Lastmodifieddate) as I posted in my answer